# I'm trying to remove a single occurrence of an element in a list

Tags: prolog

I'm using prolog and I'm trying to remove 1 element from the list. My append code works fine same with the if the element I am looking for is the first element in the list but it just says false if it is the second element in the list. Where am I going wrong

```
deleteFirst([A|X],B,Y,R):-
    A\=B,
    appendL(Y,A,[],Y1),
    deleteFirst(X,B,Y1,R).

deleteFirst([A|X],A,Y,R):-
    appendL(Y,X,[],R).
```

Comment: See: [convlist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=convlist/3)

Comment: In SWI-Prolog, you can simply do this: ```?- select(c, [a,b,c,d,e], Rest). Rest = [a, b, d, e].```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
% ---------------------------------------------
% remove the first X from List, yielding Result
% ---------------------------------------------
delete_first( X , List , Result ) :-
  append( Prefix, [X|Suffix], List ) ,
  ! ,
  append( Prefix, Suffix, Result ) .
```

The cut is needed to eliminate the choice point: otherwise, on backtracking, it will put the removed item back and try to find another matching X.

If you were to roll your own (I imagine that that is what your instructor wants), something like this, just a traversal of the list will do you:

```
delete_first( _ , []     , []     ) .  % Remove this to fail if no matching X is found
delete_first( X , [X|Rs] ,    Rs  ) :- % Once we find an X, we're done.
  !.                                   % - and eliminate the choice point
delete_first( X , [Y|Ys] , [Y|Rs] ) :- % Otherwise, put Y on the result list and recurse down
  delete_first( X , Ys, Rs ) .
```

Comment: It's much better to write this kind of predicate without a cut. The user might want it to enumerate alternative solutions, and the cut prevents that. On the other hand, if the user does not want alternative solutions, they can easily place a cut themselves. Or you could provide a pure version and a `delete_first_det` wrapper with a cut as well.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie — You might have noticed that the O.P.'s question is about removing the _first_ matching `X` from a list. Hence the cut, since removing other, alternative matching `X`s from the list is not a part of the problem statement. And hence, the comment regarding why the cut is in place.

Comment: One of us is misreading the question, and I don't think it's me. The OP is saying that their definition works for removing *the first element of the list*. I don't see them talking about the first *matching* element anywhere. And even then, my second point stands: General solution + wrapper that cuts is superior to a cut buried somewhere inside.